# How to evaluate Newton's Divided Difference Polynomial in MatLab with an unknown degree?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I already have the code that finds the coefficients for the polynomial, but how do you find a value for the polynomial if given an x coordinate in MatLab code?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the coefficients for the polynomial you created using Newton's Divided Difference Polynomial, just create a set with those coefficients then use the built in [polynomial evaluation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) function to find the value at the point you want.